# routerLink not linking (similar to href)

Tags: angular

my "routerLink" is not turning into an href type link in the html page.

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <a routerLink="/" class="logo">{{ appTitle }}</a>
    <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a routerLink="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

im a bit new to angular here

screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you have RouterModule included in you module imports ??

Comment: refer https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

Answer (score 0):

try using syntax - [routerLink]="['/about']"